# run pytest from within script and save the string output to a variable

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to run Pytest from within a script and save the output as a string.  Something like:

```
   test_output=pytest.main(['-qq', '-x', test_dir])
   print(test_output)
```

Is this possible?  I know I could write it to a file and then read the file, but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `contextlib.redirect_stdout`:

```
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import pytest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buffer = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(buffer):
        pytest.main()
    out = buffer.getvalue()
    print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have a virtual environment you cloud set there environment variables. Then you would be able to read and write them. But creating a file is probably easier.
https://www.nylas.com/blog/making-use-of-environment-variables-in-python/